# Is it possible to embed a wordpress tag page on wordpress?

Tags: tags, embed, oembed

I'm trying to use the "Embed URL" block to include another WP site's tag page on my WP page.  It seems like I'm able to embed individual posts from that site (so the theme supports embedding) but I get the error "Sorry, this content could not be embedded." when I try to use the tag page url.  Is it possible to embed a tag page?

Comment: I'd assume it only embeds post objects, and also that by "tag page" you mean an automatically created term page, which isn't a post, so no.

Comment: ah i see.  is it possible to "trick" wp into embedding it by altering the embedded site's theme?